# Explicitly create a 'previous version' of a certain file

Tags: windows-7, backup

The *Previous Versions* feature of Windows looks fine. However I don't seem to have any control on creations of backups of files in particular (as opposed to *backup everything*). If you change a file three times in a day, you'll have to wait up to 24 hours to get it backed up, and only the *latest* version will be stored.

With [VCSs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) you can do 'commits': you explicitly tell the system to save the previous version of the file, and then you overwrite the visible file. Isn't there a similar option included with the built-in backup system in Windows?

If not I'd just use a VCS or backup system but it would be nice to use something fully integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Previous Versions" are based on [Volume Shadow Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy), which essentially is a snapshot of the entire filesystem [at block level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy#Overview), so it cannot work on separate files.

You can manually create a shadow copy by using `vssadmin create shadow /for=c:`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the inner working of Shadow Copy. The fact that it runs at a low level (no files) is enough reason to me to choose an external program, in that case